# How do I add conditions with Arrayformula to hide lines when there is no data?

Tags: arrays, if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I have a column that pulls data from multiple cells to form an event description. But I would like to add some conditions to hide stuff with " " that doesn't have any information in the cell. I am not sure how can I use an IF condition within an IF within an Array formula.

```
=ArrayFormula(
IF(LEN(A:A),"Supplier 
"&I:I&" - "&J:J&" : "&K:K&""&L:L&"MT 
"&M:M&" - "&N:N&" : "&O:O&""&P:P&"MT //Hide "-"  ":" "MT" or the entire line if M:M is blank
"&Q:Q&" - "&R:R&" : "&S:S&""&T:T&"MT //Hide "-"  ":" "MT" or the entire line if Q:Q is blank

Remarks "&U:U&" //Hide the entire line if U:U is blank

Agent "&W:W&" "&X:X&" "&Y:Y&" 

Lab "&V:V,""
))))
```

Currently the result below where there are no 2nd & 3rd supplier is not very ideal.

```
Supplier 
CHEVRON - 12345678 : AAE500CST1900MT
 -  : MT
 -  : MT

Remarks 

Agent Avenger Steven 88888888 

Lab
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try like this:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(
 IF(ROW(AR:AR)=1,"Description", 
 IF(ISBLANK(AR:AR),, 
 IF(LEN(A:A),"Supplier "&
                      I:I&" - "&J:J&" : "&K:K&""&L:L&"MT "&
 IF(M:M<>"", CHAR(10)&M:M&" - "&N:N&" : "&O:O&""&P:P&"MT ", )&
 IF(Q:Q<>"", CHAR(10)&Q:Q&" - "&R:R&" : "&S:S&""&T:T&"MT ", )&
 IF(U:U<>"", CHAR(10)&CHAR(10)&"Remarks "&U:U, )&
 CHAR(10)&CHAR(10)&"Agent "&W:W&" "&X:X&" "&Y:Y& 
 CHAR(10)&CHAR(10)&"Lab "&V:V, ))))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: What does this do? IF((AR:AR="")*(M:M="")*(N:N="")*(Q:Q="")*(R:R=""),,

Comment: Ah so it check if AR and M and N and Q an R is empty? But I just want to check is e.g M:M is empty return "" instead of "&M:M&" - "&N:N&" : "&O:O&""&P:P&"MT

Comment: What does CHAR(10) do?

Comment: CHAR(10) is "new line"